# Backspacing a Number in a Calculator App

Tags: objective-c, cs193p

Can someone explain this code

```
- (IBAction)backspacePressed {
   self.display.text =[self.display.text substringToIndex:
                  [self.display.text length] - 1]; 

   if ( [self.display.text isEqualToString:@""]
      || [self.display.text isEqualToString:@"-"]) {

      self.display.text = @"0";
      self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringNumber = NO;
   }
}
```

I don't get what the 2 lines mean in objective c. || Also, I don't get the meaning of substringToIndex. How does a programmer know to use substringToIndex out of all the different methods in the documentation I saw substringFromIndex etc. There are so many. Is this saying that the strings in the index are counted and -1 means it deletes a string? How would the meaning in the apples documentation relate to deleting a character ?

Comment: -1 is used here to subtract one from the length of self.display.text, and then the result (a simple integer) is used as a parameter to pass to the function substringToIndex.  If you don't understand this, you should turn to studying more basic programming materials before moving on to worrying about how NSStrings work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments supplied with explanation of code...

```
- (IBAction)backspacePressed
{
   // This is setting the contents of self.display (a UITextField I expect) to
   // its former string, less the last character.  It has a bug, in that what
   // happens if the field is empty and length == 0?  I don't think substringToIndex
   // will like being passed -1...
   self.display.text =[self.display.text substringToIndex:
                  [self.display.text length] - 1]; 

   // This tests if the (now modified) text is empty (better is to use the length
   // method) or just contains "-", and if so sets the text to "0", and sets some
   // other instance variable, the meaning of which is unknown without further code.
   if ( [self.display.text isEqualToString:@""]
      || [self.display.text isEqualToString:@"-"]) {

      self.display.text = @"0";
      self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringNumber = NO;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

|| is an OR operator. At least one of the statements has to be true.

Look at Apple's documentation for the substringToIndex: method

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

This is stuff you could find easily with a google search.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question trojanFoe, as for NSAddict, I know how easily this can be looked up, I've looked at the documentation before I asked a question about something in the docuemntation which is valid for this website.